# Check if subject exist and append next to text box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have a rails app that has a subject text field where the user input subject code id then beside the text field will the result of other details of the subjects when I blur the text field.

form:

```
 SC_ID: <%= f.text_field "subject1", :id => "subject1"%>
```

jquery:

```
 $('#subject1').blur(function() {
      var field_value = $(this).val();
      $.post("<%= validate_subject_path %>",{subject : field_value}, function(data) {
        success: function() {

          alert("Hahaha!");
        },
        error: function() {

          alert("Subject not found!");
        }
      });

    });
```

controller:

```
 def validate_subject
    sc_id = params[:subject].to_i
    @subject = Subject.find_by_sc_id(sc_id)
    string = "#{@subject.id}"
    return string
    render :layout => false
   end
```

routes:

```
 map.validate_subject '/subjects/validate_subject', :controller => "subjects", :action => 'validate_subject'
```

But when I try to blur no alert box is coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.post` call is wrong, it should be something like this:

```
  $.post("<%= validate_subject_path %>",{subject : field_value}, function(data) {
      // not returning a hash
      alert("Hahaha!");
  });
```

If you really when to react on failures than you need to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/